# how to destroy instantiate object unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class myscript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform platform;
    public float z = 0.0f;

    void Update () 
    {
        float c_z=0.0f;

        Instantiate(platform,new Vector3(z++,0,0),Quaternion.identity);
        Camera.main.transform.Translate (0,0,c_z=c_z+0.1f);
    }
}
```

In the above code my platform is instantiated and I have to destroy tail of my platform when my camera move ahead. How?

Comment: and what do you mean with tail? you want the area behind you to despawn ? you want the whole platform to despawn ?

Comment: You realise your current code is going to create a new instance of a GameObject several times every single second the game is running and this script is active, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class myscript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform platform;
    public float z = 0.0f;
    private GameObject _obj;

    void Update () 
    {
        float c_z=0.0f;

        _obj = Instantiate(platform,new Vector3(z++,0,0),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Camera.main.transform.Translate (0,0,c_z=c_z+0.1f);
    }
}
```

Then just call `Destroy(obj)` whenever you are ready to destroy the platform.